# Phonegap (Cordova) mailto link with CC not working

Tags: ios, cordova, mailto, carbon-copy

Hello I am trying to add a simple link something like:

```
<a href="mailto:me@mydomain.com&cc=me2@domain.com&subject=mysubject">Contact</a>
```

Instead of putting each content in the respect field in the emails (to, cc, subject) the mail app in IOS puts the entire string in the "to" field.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query string should start with "?" instead of "&".

So the final result is:

```
<a href="mailto:me@mydomain.com?cc=me2@domain.com&subject=mysubject">Contact</a>
```